# Sails.js redirect with param

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, sails.js

what is the best way to redirect inside a Sails.js Controller from one route to another and transfer some data at the same time. 
My situation is that I've got one route that creates some data and the redirects back to another route. My problem is that I don't know how to transfer an error message (if one happens) back to the other route (because I want to display it there).

Bruno

Comment: Not sure if this can be done. At this point, I'd transfer some of your controller logic into a service, so that you can use the same code in both routes.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Do you need the second route or is it just for showing error messages? I'd probably pass the error message (or an error code identifier) in the URL as a GET parameter, or use [flash messages](https://github.com/dudemelo/sails-hook-flash).

Comment: The second one implements some logic and only if an error happens i want to pass it to the first route ... Otherwise I just use res.redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that I don't know how to transfer an error message (if
>   one happens) back to the other route (because I want to display it
>   there).

Sails@v0.12 includes flash middleware in form of https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash:

```
req.flash('error', payload);
res.redirect(307, '/');
return;
```

To get the error in another controller:

```
var error = req.flash('error');
```

Comment: looks good ... I will try it out later ... but thank you already